# Python package installation issue: Cannot install 'pickle5' due to error building wheels. Solutions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

i have problems with my packages because every time i want to install some package then sometimes this error is showing up
any ideas how to fix it?

i want to install `pickle5` (because `pickle` does not exist) and every time i want to install it then error shows up

error:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: pickle5
  Building wheel for pickle5 (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pickle5 (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [17 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pickle5
      copying pickle5\pickle.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pickle5
      copying pickle5\pickletools.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pickle5
      copying pickle5\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pickle5
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pickle5\test
      copying pickle5\test\pickletester.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pickle5\test
      copying pickle5\test\test_pickle.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pickle5\test
      copying pickle5\test\test_picklebuffer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pickle5\test
      copying pickle5\test\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pickle5\test
      running build_ext
      building 'pickle5._pickle' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pickle5
Failed to build pickle5
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pickle5, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Answer (score 0):

It says that you need to have Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater installed in order to build the pickle5 package.

Visit the [Microsoft C++ Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/) page and download the installer for the latest version.

Comment: if its unable to install try import pickle